# Routing Error : uninitialized constant when split controller routes into namespaced route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have routes like this below. Is it possible if I have routes like this ?

```
#config/routes
resources :subscribers, only: [:index, :show]

namespace :admin do
    resources :subscribers, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :create, :destroy]
end
```

I have tried to run *rake routes* and the result is

```
admin_subscribers     POST /admin/subscribers(.:format)     admin/subscribers#create
new_admin_subscriber  GET  /admin/subscribers/new(.:format) admin/subscribers#new
edit_admin_subscriber GET  /admin/subscribers/:id/edit(.:format) admin/subscribers#edit
admin_subscriber      PUT  /admin/subscribers/:id(.:format) admin/subscribers#update
                      DELETE /admin/subscribers/:id(.:format)    admin/subscribers#destroy
subscribers           GET    /subscribers(.:format)         subscribers#index
subscriber            GET    /subscribers/:id(.:format)     subscribers#show
```

the result was appropriate with my expectation, but when i run my RSpec i got errors

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Admin::SubscribersController
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I added this code below in my Rspec Helper too

```
#spec/spec_helper.rb

Spork.each_run do
###

   if /spork/i =~ $0 || RSpec.configuration.drb?
     ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
   end

###

end
```

But, if I fire my browser to htt**://l*alhost:3000/admin/subscribers/new, everything is fine. 
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

If you want to route `/admin/subscribers` to `SubscribersController` (without the `Admin::` module prefix), you could use `scope` instead of `namespace`

```
#config/routes
resources :subscribers, only: [:index, :show]

scope "/admin" do
  resources :subscribers, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :create, :destroy]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's much need for you to namespace this under `admin`. You could just fill in all the actions on `SubscribersController` and set the permissions on `create`, `update` etc. appropriately.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to create page for admin only. so, to reduce some routing/URL confusion, I split into namespace for admin